# Support of JsonView annotation in Restlet

Tags: json, jackson, restlet

I am trying to create different view of JSON using Restlet. With 2.3 of JAX-RS module it is possible to annotate JAX-RS resources with JsonView from Jackson framework:

```
public class Resource {

  @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
  public List<Object> getElements() {
    ...
    return someResultList;
  }
}
```

How can we reproduce the same behavior in Restlet? Is is already supported ?

Comment: Your question is very interesting, I've added a RFE for that: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/1144. There is no support yet in the framework, but it is possible to write a dedicated class that makes the bridge.